# Having trouble setting table values from database in JavaFX

Tags: sql, javafx

Im trying to set up my table so that i can get database values and set them to the table columns but its refusing to populate the table. There is a particular error that is displaying and the error itself is saying

```
incompatible types: PropertyValueFactory<Object,Object> cannot be converted to Callback<CellDataFeatures<CAP#1,CAP#2>,ObservableValue<CAP#2>>
```

Here is my code

```
AnchorPane AnchorPane;
    Connection connection;
    String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=Charis;username=sa;password=";

        @FXML
        TableView <Stock> tblStockTake;
    @FXML
    TableColumn <?,?> colStockTakeBy;
    @FXML
    TableColumn<?,?> colNumberOfPurple;
    @FXML
    TableColumn<?,?> colNumberOfGold;
    @FXML
    TableColumn<?,?> colDate;
    ObservableList <Stock> data;


    @FXML
    TextField txtNumberOfSilver,txtNumberOfPurple,txtProductName,txtStockTakeBy;
    @FXML
    Button btnAddStock,btnUpdateStock,btnClearFields;
    StockTakeHandler handler;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        // TODO
        animate();
        handler = new StockTakeHandler();
        data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        getDataFromDatabase();
        setCellTable();

    }   

    @FXML
    public void addStock(ActionEvent event){

       //add stock to the database

        if(txtNumberOfSilver.getText().equals("")
                ||txtNumberOfPurple.getText().equals("")
                ||txtProductName.getText().equals("")
                ||txtStockTakeBy.getText().equals("")){

           showMessage();

        }else{

           //get the id number

            String productName = txtProductName.getText().toString();
            String stockTakeBy = txtStockTakeBy.getText().toString();
            int numberOfPurple = Integer.parseInt(txtNumberOfSilver.getText().toString());
            int numberOfSilver = Integer.parseInt(txtNumberOfPurple.getText().toString());
            handler.addStockToDatabase(productName, stockTakeBy, numberOfPurple,numberOfSilver);
            clearFields();

        }


    }
    @FXML
    public void clearFields(){
        //FXML txtNumberOfSilver,txtNumberOfPurple,txtProductName,txtStockTakeBy;
        txtNumberOfSilver.setText("");
        txtStockTakeBy.setText("");
        txtNumberOfPurple.setText("");
        txtNumberOfSilver.setText("");
    }


    private void showMessage() {

        //check if there are any empty fields
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Please Check For Empty Fields");

    }

    @FXML
    public void updateStock(ActionEvent event){

             if(txtNumberOfSilver.getText().equals("")
                ||txtNumberOfPurple.getText().equals("")
                ||txtProductName.getText().equals("")
                ||txtStockTakeBy.getText().equals("")){

           showMessage();

        }else{

            String productName = txtProductName.getText().toString();
            String stockTakeBy = txtStockTakeBy.getText().toString();
            int numberOfPurple = Integer.parseInt(txtNumberOfSilver.getText().toString());
            int numberOfSilver = Integer.parseInt(txtNumberOfPurple.getText().toString());
            handler.updateStockInDatabase(productName, stockTakeBy, numberOfPurple,numberOfSilver);
            clearFields();
    }


}

    private void getDataFromDatabase() {

    data.clear();

        try {
            Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
            String sql = "select * from StockTake";

            Statement statement = connection.createStatement();

            ResultSet rSet = statement.executeQuery(sql);

            while(rSet.next()) {


                String productName = rSet.getString("productName");
                String stockTakeBy = rSet.getString("stockTakeBy") + "";
                String numberOfPurple= rSet.getString("numberOfPurple") + "";
                                String numberOfGold = rSet.getString("numberOfGold") + "";
                String currentDate = rSet.getString("currentDate") + "";

                                System.out.println(productName);

                Stock list = new Stock(productName,stockTakeBy,numberOfPurple,numberOfGold,currentDate);

                data.add(list);

                }

            tblStockTake.setItems(data);

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
    }


    private void setCellTable() {

     colStockTakeBy.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("productName"));
    /*colNumberOfPurple.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("itemDescription"));
    colNumberOfGold.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("supplierCode"));
    colDate.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("date"));**/

       }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using wildcards for the type arguments to each `TableColumn`. Then later, the type arguments of your `PropertyValueFactory` are being inferred as `Object`. In other words, you have:

```java
TableColumn<?, ?> col = ...;
col.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Object, Object>("..."));`
```

And therein lies the problem: `Object != ?`. You should replace the wildcards with actual types. For example:

```java
// all type arguments are just a guess based on field name
@FXML TableColumn<Stock, LocalDate> colStockTakeBy;
@FXML TableColumn<Stock, Number> colNumberOfPurple;
@FXML TableColumn<Stock, Number> colNumberOfGold;
@FXML TableColumn<Stock, LocalDate> colDate;
```

The first type argument should match the type argument of the `TableView` that the `TableColumn` belongs to. The second type argument should be the type the cells of that column will display.

---

As an aside, in this method:

```java
private void showMessage() {

    //check if there are any empty fields
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Please Check For Empty Fields");

}
```

You're using a class from the Swing API: `JOptionPane`. Unless absolutely necessary, avoid mixing different UI toolkits together. Doing otherwise just adds unnecessary complexity and can lead to hard-to-diagnose bugs. You should use the equivalent JavaFX API instead—see [`Alert`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/Alert.html).

```java
private void showMessage() {
  Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.ERROR);
  alert.initOwner(tblStockTake.getScene().getWindow());
  alert.setHeaderText(null);
  alert.setContentText("Please check for empty fields.");
  alert.showAndWait();
}
```

Comment: its still not diaplaying anything

Comment: That's a separate problem from your current question. Your current problem was a compilation error, which the above _should_ fix. If there's now another problem, consider asking a new question; provide a [mre] demonstrating the problem and the exact error(s) you're getting.